# Unable to get list elements when using parcelable objects

Tags: android, parcelable, custom-lists, parcel

I have an application that has a service and an activity. My base class and list class are implementing parcelable. And the list class uses writeTypedList()/readTypedList() to parcel a custom list. However when retrieving the list I'm getting the correct number of elements, but am getting a null pointer exception when trying to access any elements besides the first element of the list. When doing a writeToParcel() I can see that 2 elements with correct data are being added, but when doing a readFromParcel() only the first element shows up and the second element is null.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Here's my list container class:

```
public class WfdDeviceList implements Parcelable {
private static final String TAG = "WfdDeviceList";
public List<WfdDevice> devList;

public WfdDeviceList() { devList = new ArrayList<WfdDevice>(); }
public WfdDeviceList(Parcel parcel) {
    this();
    readFromParcel(parcel);
}

public void clear() {
    devList.clear();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    Log.d(TAG, "writeToParcel(): " + devList.size());
    Log.d(TAG, "flags: " + flags);
    for (WfdDevice device : devList) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Writing: " + device.name);
    }
    parcel.writeTypedList(devList);
}

public void readFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
    Log.d(TAG, "readFromParcel()");
    parcel.readTypedList(devList, WfdDevice.CREATOR);
    Log.d(TAG, "Size: " + devList.size());
    WfdDevice device = devList.get(0);
    Log.d(TAG, "Device1: " + device.name);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<WfdDeviceList> CREATOR = new Parcelable
.Creator<WfdDeviceList>() {
    public WfdDeviceList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new WfdDeviceList(in);
    }
    public WfdDeviceList[] newArray(int size) {
        return new WfdDeviceList[size];
    }
};
} 

public class WfdDevice implements Parcelable {
public String macAddress;
public String name;
public WfdDeviceType type;
public String ipAddr;
public String pin;
public boolean isConnected;

public WfdDevice() {}
    public WfdDevice(Parcel parcel) {
    readFromParcel(parcel);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

WfdDeviceType getType(int type) {
    switch(type) {
    case 1:
        return WfdDeviceType.source;
    case 2:
        return WfdDeviceType.primarySink;
    case 3:
        return WfdDeviceType.secondarySink;
    case 4:
        return WfdDeviceType.sourcePrimarySink;
    default:
    case 0:
        return WfdDeviceType.unknown;
    }
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
    parcel.writeString(this.macAddress);
    parcel.writeString(this.name);
    parcel.writeInt(type.ordinal());
    parcel.writeString(this.ipAddr);
    parcel.writeString(this.pin);
    parcel.writeInt(this.isConnected == true ? 1 : 0);
}

public void readFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
    this.macAddress = parcel.readString();
    this.name = parcel.readString();
    this.type = getType(parcel.readInt());
    this.ipAddr = parcel.readString();
    this.pin = parcel.readString();
    this.isConnected = (parcel.readInt() == 1 ? true : false);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<WfdDevice> CREATOR = new Parcelable
.Creator<WfdDevice>() {
    public WfdDevice createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new WfdDevice(in);
    }
    public WfdDevice[] newArray(int size) {
        return new WfdDevice[size];
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the issue. It seems to be that having the enum type WfdDeviceType in my WfdDevice class was somehow causing the issue. I've since changed that type from an enum to an int and the problem has gone away.